# SharePoint 2013 only Term Store admin can see the term

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata, runwithelevatedprivileges

I have built a global navigation solution that replace the SuiteBarLinks and use a term store to store the links for the navigation.

In my testing environment, Farm Account is granted to Term Store Administrators. By logged in as Farm Account, I created a TermGroup "Global Navigation", and under there i have some term sets and terms.

My VS solution have following code:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
   using (SPSite thisSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.AlternateUrls[0].Uri.AbsoluteUri))
   {
      TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(thisSite);
      TermStoreCollection store = session.TermStores;
      //load the terms and build the menu html
      try
      {
         //...
      }
   }
}
```

The code build and run fine. If I open the site as Farm Account , the navigation show up perfectly.

But if I login as normal user, the navigation does not show up.

If I login as Site admin and go Site Setting -> Term Store Management
I can see the Global Navigation Group but I cannot expand it, thus I cannot see the terms inside. So perhaps it is something related to the permission.

So how can I grant user read access to the term? And I guess the SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges should tickle this but it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Ok..I solved my problem... But some reason, I must have to check the "Available for Tagging" checkbox for the term set.

I presume this option is used for controlling if allow user to use such term in tagging item. My thought is if I access the terms in code I don't have to have it checked, but I am wrong...